# How to display list view in visualforce page and make it visually pleasant and include autoscrolling

Tags: visualforce, list-view, scrolling, enhancedlist

I want to display a queue list view on monitor that displays case numbers and their status. I have written the following visualforce code:

```
 <apex:page sidebar="false">

   <apex:enhancedList type="Case" height="300" rowsPerPage="25" 
   ListId="00B4P0000080x0y" customizable="False" />

 </apex:page>
```

Here is the screenshot of the page:
[image]

However, it is not visually pleasant. I want to hide all the extra things that appear on the page e.g. sidebar, header, all the buttons (New Case, Accept, Close e.t.c.) from the view as well as if the list is too big, it should autoscroll. Basically how we see things on monitor usually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should build your own custom list controller, to bring the records that you want and create your own "list view" perhaps using an apex:pageBlockTable

List controller: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_custom_list_controller.htm

Page Block Table: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help. However I don't know what data to display. I will only get a listview from third-party so I am looking for the quick options to display it on visualforce.

Comment: @CommonCare I actually explored the option you mentioned. Fetching Cases and then displaying them using PageBlock. However, I have a quick question, is there a way to make visualforce pae dynamic i.e if I add a new case, would that automatically be added to the list or I would have to refresh the page to see teh chnaes in teh list?

Comment: @Student Yes you can, using the Streaming API https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_generic_vfp_intro.htm but I don't suggest it. Even standard list views need to be refreshed manually to see new cases. You'd be introducing a huge amount of complexity to your page.